# How to get rid of blank space under SimpleViewer Gallery?

Tags: css

I am working on a website and have embedded a Simpleviewer gallery into one of my pages. There is a blank white area under the gallery that I can't make go away. My ultimate goal is to have no need to scroll vertically on the page.

Here is a link to the page: http://www.tuckermatthewsphoto.com/a...tomotive1.html

Any help is greatly appreciated. This is driving me absolutely nuts.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured it out for myself.

Since I knew that there was nothing on the bottom of the page that I needed, I decided on trying to hide the scrollbar, so I added into the css file:

body { overflow:hidden; }

No more scrolling! This seems like it would be a pretty useful trick, so far it works in Safari and Firefox.